# Plot in python without matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jython

I'm writing a program for TopSpin, an NMR processing software from Bruker. TopSpin runs the python scripts in it's own environment using jython. The python version it returns is 2.5.* (I don't remember the last one).

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
>> 2.5.*
```

As the code is executed in it's own environment, I cannot update the version of python/jython and I also cannot install missing packages.

For my current project I would need a functionality to plot the values of two lists. The first list on the x-axis and the second one on the y-axis.
For this task I wanted to use matplotlib's function `plot(xlist, ylist)`. Unfortunately TopSpin throws an error at me, saying that the package `matplotlib` does not exist. As I can't install the package (or at least I have no idea how I should), I now need a workaround.

Is there a way I could call a python script that runs in the normal environment of my computer (like idle) where python 3.6.3 and matplotlib are installed? Ideally this could generate the plot and ship it back to the TopSpin python program.

Or is there an other workaround that enables me to plot my data and show it to the user/save it on the disk, that does not rely on fancy or new packages?

Comment: Google this:  "python virtualenv".  It creates another environment where python version is different from your current version. Goodluck.

Comment: This will not work. In TopSpin you can only save a `.py` file that is then called in the TopSpin command  prompt by typing it's name. So I can't put the file in a virtual environment. :-/

Comment: matplotlib doesn't work in Jython - it relies on C modules. You could try generating the data in TopSpin, then loading the processed result in the normal environment of your machine. See NMRglue - https://github.com/jjhelmus/nmrglue/issues/13 - which can read Bruker data.